# ctypes MessageBoxW returns unexpected chinese characters

Tags: python, windows, ctypes

I use the following code to display a popup message

```
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    import ctypes

    def message_box(title, text, style):
        return ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text, title, style)

if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    message_box('Error', 'Phat sinh loi Unicode, kiem tra chi tiet trong %s' % common.ERR_LOG_FILE, 0)
```

When my app runs in windows 7, the popup contains all unexpected CHINESE characters while my original message (in the code snippet) only contains alphabet characters. This is the first time I use ctypes and quite confused.
Someone pls explain and help me solve it.

[popup result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmFeY.jpg)

Comment: `MessageBoxW` expects UTF-16 strings.  Try wrapping your strings with [`ctypes.c_wchar_p(...)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_wchar_p) first.

Comment: Always, when using `ctypes`, define `.argtypes` and `.restype` for the functions you are calling.  The defaults are not always what you want and defining them also does type-checking.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using Python 2.  Python 2's strings are byte strings and marshaled as byte strings (`char*`).  Python 3's strings are Unicode strings and marshaled as wide strings (`wchar_t*`).  Without defining `.argtypes`, `ctypes` won't error check and happily pass the wrong type.

To call `MessageBoxW` on Python 2, pass Unicode strings instead, but it is better to define `.argtypes` and `.restype` so `ctypes` can type check and tell you when the parameter is wrong:

```
#python2
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes as w

user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32')
MessageBox = user32.MessageBoxW
MessageBox.argtypes = w.HWND,w.LPCWSTR,w.LPCWSTR,w.UINT
MessageBox.restype = ctypes.c_int

MessageBox(None, u'message', u'title', 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally fixed it like this :

```
def message_box(title, text, style=0):
    return ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, unicode(text), unicode(title), style)
```